# How to make my selection not repeat in the drop down list. Why does the list continue to populate?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, radio-button, return-value, displayobject

```
<script language="javascript">
        function init()
        {
            changeSelection();
        }

        function changeSelection()
        {
            displayGenderOptions(getSelectedRadioButton());
        }

        function getSelectedRadioButton()
        {
            var button = document.clubForm.gender;
            for ( count = 0; count < button.length; count++ )
            {
                if (button[count].checked)
                    return button[count].value;
            }
        }

        function displayGenderOptions(selectedValue)
        {
            var selector = document.getElementById('clubChoices');
            if (selectedValue == 'male')
            {
                // The following is an example. Replace it with correct selections
                selector.options[selector.options.length] = new Option('120 -140', '5'); The 120-140 selection should be displayed after clicking the Male Radio button. I need a code to do this but I'm not sure what it is. It keeps populated the list , I only want to display male and female selection separately. Hope this makes sense.
            }
            else
            {
                // The following is an example. Replace it with correct selections
                selector.options[selector.ClubForm.index] =  Option('85 - 110', '0'); // I need three selections to list in the drop down menu. The 85-100 should be displayed after clicking the Female radio button.
            }
        }

        function chooseClub()
        {
            // Add your code here to select which club for the distance and gender <--Not sure what to add here..or how to display my results. Run program to get an idea of what it does. It's supposed to display the correct selection of clubs used for Male or Female. Bare with me I'm new to these forums and not sure how to word what I am looking for. Thanks. I would just like to put the right selection to go with the Male Female radio button
        }
        </script>



<body onload='init();'>
<h1>CIS 122 Lab 3</h1>
<div class="container">
<h2>SELECT-O-CLUB</h2>
<form name="clubForm" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px;"><input name="gender" value="male" checked="checked" onchange="changeSelection();" type="radio" />Male <input name="gender" value="female" onchange="changeSelection();" type="radio" />Female</div>
<select id="clubChoices" style="margin-left: 5px;" onchange="chooseClub();"></select>
<div name="result" class="result"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

//I also need to check to see if the HTML code is right to display the list of club choices? This is driving me nuts I can't find any help manual on this at all. Male and Female list should both have different selections in the drop box answers. I have been up for hours daily trying to figure this out it is very hard since our class does not offer a JavaScript book to go along with. I know the code is something simple that is missing but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `document.clubForm.gender;` valid?

Comment: Also `var selector = document.getElementById('clubChoices');` will return the same value regardless of what option is selected.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('clubChoices').options[document.getElementById('clubChoices').selectedIndex].value`

Comment: Hmmm should I get rid of var selector all together?

Comment: Keep it if you want but it seems there's a logical error somewhere where you select the incorrect option value and when you compare `if selection == 'male' or else` it'll always go to else since selection will never be 'male'.

Comment: console.log all your values and see what's going wrong.

Comment: yeah I think the selector.options[ClubForm.Index] should just read selector.options.index also. Basically learning this stuff as I go sometimes a good explination is all that is needed. I'll work on messing with the code to see if I can get it to work.